# Rails + Spork + Minitest + Autotest and models

Tags: ruby-on-rails, autotest, spork, minitest

I installed Rails + Spork + Minitest + Autotest as shown by S. Christoffer Eliesen in [how-to-combine-autotest-and-spork-in-rails-testing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4274499/how-to-combine-autotest-and-spork-in-rails-testing) and it works great for tests that doesn't involve the database. It doesn't work if I add a model though:

```
rails g scaffold post name:string
rake db:migrate
```

It then gives me the following error:

```
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: Could not find table 'posts'
```

How can I make it "see" the database/table changes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to run the migration in the test environment as well.

```
rake db:migrate RAILS_ENV=test
```